# Two js functions execute one after another?

Tags: jquery

I have a function in which I call two function and I want to run first function completely then second executed but I am not able to get control over it.

```
DayCalendar: function(ProviderId, ResourceId, FacilityId, CriteriaDate, statusid) {
    MDVisionService.lookups("GetAppointmentStatus").done(function(result) {
        appstatus = result;
    });
    Scheduling_Calendar.SearchDaySlotSchedule(ProviderId, ResourceId, FacilityId, CriteriaDate, statusid).done(function (response) {
        if (response.status != false) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move second function `Scheduling_Calendar.SearchDaySlotSchedule` to the callback of first function `MDVisionService.lookups`

```
DayCalendar: function(ProviderId, ResourceId, FacilityId, CriteriaDate, statusid) {
    MDVisionService.lookups("GetAppointmentStatus").done(function(result) {
        appstatus = result;
        Scheduling_Calendar.SearchDaySlotSchedule(ProviderId, ResourceId, FacilityId, CriteriaDate, statusid).done(function (response) {
            if (response.status != false) {
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like:

```
DayCalendar: function(ProviderId, ResourceId, FacilityId, CriteriaDate, statusid, callback) {
MDVisionService.lookups("GetAppointmentStatus").done(function(result) {
    appstatus = result;
    //callback(arguments) //if you need to call it here
}); 
callback(arguments);
}

schedule: function(ProviderId, ResourceId, FacilityId, CriteriaDate, statusid){
 var args = arguments;
 return function() { 
   return Scheduling_Calendar.SearchDaySlotSchedulea.apply(this, args).done(function (response) {
    if (response.status != false) {
    }
   });
 } 

//call
DayCalendar(ProviderId, ResourceId, FacilityId, CriteriaDate, statusid, schedule());
```